# Addition of 2 numbers and give corresponding outputs depending on the number of digits got from the addition using C

Tags: c

The Question goes this way :

***Add two numbers and if the addition of two numbers gives the result in single digit print YES and if the result of the two numbers is in double digit print NO***

Comment: You'll get a better response if you try to write the code yourself then post a more specific question if you get stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an idea. It is enough to check whether the result of the addition is less than 10 and greater than -10 if the numbers are signed.:)